# How to set default web page for first Wifi connection?

Tags: networking, network-programming, wifi, modem

How to set default web page for first connection to network via modem?

Comment: You need to have the connections coming in via a proxy which will redirect the users

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is that for everybody connecting to wifi, to be redirected to a web site, I would configure my access point DHCP to specify a default gateway to a specific server. Then this server can act as a proxy and present a specific web page based on certain criteria like device authenticated or first request. You could also use Web Proxy Autodiscovery Protocol.